# CSS border-radius bleed with dark colors

Tags: css

I've got a containing box that has a `border-radius` then I have an element within the container that also has a `border-radius` set, and it butts up against the edges of the box.

The containing box is "bleeding" around the edges of the interior box:

[image]

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/Shpigford/RUAMx/

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy to fix setting bigger radius for container border:

```
div {
    background:white;
    border-radius: 5px 8px 8px 5px;
}
```

See here http://jsfiddle.net/RUAMx/2/

In addition you don't have to use -webkit and -moz preffixes anymore, support for border-radius is [good enough](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius).

Answer (score 0):

one of the solution just move anchor tag a bit, like this http://jsfiddle.net/RUAMx/3/

```
a {
    color:white;
    float:right;
    display:block;
    background:#201f23;
    padding:10px 20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
}
```

and to compensate this -5px on anchor use 5px to div container

```
div {
    background:white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: seems like even 2px would be sufficient